# How do I handle server redirects on IIS to route requests to two different domains?

Tags: redirects, server, iis, migration, dns-servers

I have a domain `www.example.com` which is running on IIS server and the site content is in ASP.NET. I am migrating part of the site (`www` to `www`) to AEM and the rest of it will sit on `old.example.com` (`www` to `old`).

I understand this migration isn't ideal (trust me I have discussed at length with the client) but we need to migrate this way. How do we handle these redirects where some are going to `www` and others to `old`? I was told by IT I need to point the whole `www` to AEM and have AEM handle redirects to either `www` or old. I would ideally want to have the server handle all of the requests to send them to `www` or `old` accordingly.

Comment: Since I had to look it up, AEM is [Adobe Experience Manager](https://helpx.adobe.com/support/experience-manager/6-5.html).  Is that a separate server or is it something that runs on top of IIS?

Comment: AEM is the new content management system we are migrating to for some of the new pages. The rest of the pages which aren't ready for this launch will be sent to the current CMS while the new pages that are ready are sent to the new CMS (AEM).

Comment: Does the new CMS run on the same server?

Comment: AEM, the new CMS, is running on a different server.

Comment: I guess that the IT specialist has given you the best solution for that case. You need to point the whole server to AEM and handle the redirects from it.